# SSRS choosing dynamic Columns

Tags: string, dynamic, reporting-services, composite

For my report I need to choose which Columns to access from the Database dynamically. To be more precice:

In the Database the Columns are named like this:

```
FCST_Sales_2014_Q4_with_SF
FCST_Sales_2015_Q1_with_SF
FCST_Sales_2015_Q2_with_SF
FCST_Sales_2015_Q3_with_SF
```

I need the Report to choose the current year and quarter, therefore I'm using the `Now()` Function to composite the expression I need. For Example:

```
=Year(Now())
```

And

```
=Switch(
  Month(Now()) = 1, 1, 
  Month(Now()) = 2, 1, 
  Month(Now()) = 3, 1, 
  Month(Now()) = 4, 2,
  Month(Now()) = 5, 2,
  Month(Now()) = 6, 2, 
  Month(Now()) = 7, 3, 
  Month(Now()) = 8, 3,
  Month(Now()) = 9, 3,
  Month(Now()) = 10, 4,
  Month(Now()) = 11, 4,
  Month(Now()) = 12, 4)
```

The Result is `2014` and `4` which is exactly what I need. If I'm using the following:

```
=("Fields!FCST_Sales_" + CStr(Year(Now())) + "_Q" + CStr(Switch(Month(Now()) = 1, 1, Month(Now()) = 2,1,Month(Now()) = 3,1,Month(Now()) = 4, 2, Month(Now()) = 5,2,Month(Now()) = 6,2,Month(Now()) = 7,3,Month(Now()) = 8,3,Month(Now()) = 9,3,Month(Now()) = 10, 4, Month(Now()) = 11,4,Month(Now()) = 12,4)) + "_with_SF")
```

I get exactly the String I need (`FCST_Sales_2014_Q4_with_SF`) but the problem is, that I somehow can't use the `.Value` operation. If I add `Sum()` and `.Value` to the expression I create I get the error message, that `.Value` is no member of String. The expression I used is:

```
=Sum(("Fields!FCST_Sales_" + CStr(Year(Now())) + "_Q" + CStr(Switch(Month(Now()) = 1,1, Month(Now()) = 2,1,Month(Now()) = 3,1,Month(Now()) = 4,2, Month(Now()) = 5,2,Month(Now()) = 6,2,Month(Now()) = 7,3,Month(Now()) = 8,3,Month(Now()) = 9,3,Month(Now()) = 10, 4, Month(Now()) = 11,4,Month(Now()) = 12,4)) + "_with_SF").Value)
```

Is there a Solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't build a field like that - you are actually building a string. What you want to do is build the name of the fields to look up in the `Fields` collection, so instead of this:

```
Fields!FieldName.Value
```

looks like this:

```
Fields("FieldName").Value
```

So you could use your very large expression:

```
=Sum(Fields("FCST_Sales_" + CStr(Year(Now())) + "_Q" + CStr(Switch(Month(Now()) = 1, 1, Month(Now()) = 2, 1, Month(Now()) = 3, 1, Month(Now()) = 4,2, Month(Now()) = 5, 2,Month(Now()) = 6, 2, Month(Now()) = 7, 3, Month(Now()) = 8, 3, Month(Now()) = 9, 3, Month(Now()) = 10, 4, Month(Now()) = 11, 4, Month(Now()) = 12, 4)) + "_with_SF").Value)
```

You can also simplify that expression. To get the quarter, you only need to do this:

```
(Month(Today) + 2) \ 3
```

so your expression comes down to

```
=Sum(Fields("FCST_Sales_" + CStr(Year(Today)) + "_Q" + CStr((Month(Today) + 2) \ 3) + "_with_SF").Value)
```

**Alternative method: Using SQL to build the field name dynamically**

There is another possibly simpler way using a dynamic SQL string returning a consistent field name. For example, if your SQL looked like this:

```
SELECT FCST_Sales_2014_Q4_with_SF 
FROM MyTable
```

you can convert that to a string expression that resolves to a SQL statement. Right-click the dataset, choose Dataset Properties and click the expression editor `fx` button beside the query. Now we can build the SQL statement from a string, like so

```
="SELECT FCST_Sales_" + CStr(Year(Today)) + "_Q" + CStr((Month(Today) + 2) \ 3) + "_with_SF AS FCST_Sales "
&"FROM MyTable"
```

Now you are dynamically building the field name in the SQL query and it gets returned aliased to `FCST_Sales` in your dataset so you can easily use a known field value throughout your report, making your calculations much easier:

```
=Fields!FCST_Sales.Value
```

and

```
=SUM(Fields!FCST_Sales.Value)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, also your simplified expression was very helpful. Thanks for your help.